# Recent Papers on Spectrum analysis

Tags: reference-request

This is more of a soft question, I am currently writing a paper for my Master's in Mathematics and my topic of choice has been to focus on the Mathematical techniques behind Spectrum Analysis.

For my initial reading I have focused on Kay & Marple's paper Spectrum Analysis- A Modern Perspective, however "modern" in this context is relative to 1981.

I was wondering if anybody was aware of paper's published in the last few years (2005-onwards) which dealt with more recent developments. Currently I am focusing on Prony and ARMA techniques, with a contrast to Wavelets. However as I am hopefully going to be receiving actual experimental data (analyzing output of power from a laser) I would like to have access to a range of current ideas to analyse the data and present a contrast.

Ideally i am looking for papers that give a treatment of the mathematical concepts behind the techniques.

Thanks

edit: I have been searching IEEE etc, and have a large variety of papers but i was hoping that i could be pointed towards good quality papers before i attempt to read them all to discover which are more helpful.